# build user item matrix with surprise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recommendation-engine

I wrote the code below for building the user item matrix and the similarity matrix, using surprise for movie lens datasets. With the 100K dataset it is fine, but I tried to compile it for the 10M dataset, it does not finished for more than 4 hours. I believe the reason is the iterations. Can you please help me with this.

```
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from surprise import Dataset, Reader
from surprise import SVD

from scipy.spatial import distance

file_path = os.path.expanduser('movie_lens_10M.dat')
reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating timestamp', sep='::')
data = Dataset.load_from_file(file_path, reader=reader)
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()

# Build an algorithm, and train it.
algo = SVD()
algo.fit(trainset)

data = pd.read_csv('movie_lens_10M.dat',
                   names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'time'],
                   engine='python', delimiter='::')

rating_matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(np.max(data.movie_id.values), np.max(data.user_id.values)), dtype=np.uint8)
rating_matrix[data.movie_id.values - 1, data.user_id.values - 1] = data.rating.values

# build item user matrix, if 0 than predict
for i in range(np.max(data.movie_id.values)):
    for j in range(np.max(data.user_id.values)):
        if rating_matrix[i][j] == 0:
            rating_matrix[i][j] = algo.predict(str(j + 1), str(i + 1))[3]

np.savetxt("rating_matrix.txt", rating_matrix, delimiter="\t")

# build similarity matrix
similarity_matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(np.max(data.user_id.values), np.max(data.user_id.values)), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(np.max(data.user_id.values)):
    for j in range(i, np.max(data.user_id.values)):
        similarity_matrix[i][j] = 1 - distance.correlation(rating_matrix[:, i], rating_matrix[:, j])
        similarity_matrix[j][i] = similarity_matrix[i][j]


np.savetxt("similarity_matrix.txt", similarity_matrix, delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently calculate large similarity matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106265/efficiently-calculate-large-similarity-matrix)

Comment: no, I used dtype=np.uint8

Comment: n_factors matters. default = 100. Try a small number: algo = SVD(n_factors = 10)

Answer (score 0):

n_factors matters. default = 100. Try a small number:

```
algo = SVD(n_factors = 10)
```